# I am trying to allocate as less memory as possible to better understand the move semantics in c++

Tags: c++

I have written this piece of code for better understanding the move semantic:

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Var.h"

struct AllocationMetrics {
    uint32_t totalAllocated = 0;
    uint32_t totalFreed = 0;

    uint32_t CurrentUsage() {
        return totalAllocated - totalFreed;
    }
};

static AllocationMetrics allocationMetrics;

void *operator new(size_t size) {
    allocationMetrics.totalAllocated += size;
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void *memory, size_t size) {
    allocationMetrics.totalFreed += size;
    return free(memory);
}

static void printMemoryUsage () {
    std::cout << "Current memory usage (bytes): " << allocationMetrics.CurrentUsage() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    printMemoryUsage();
    Var v1{"0011223344556677889"};
    printMemoryUsage();

    Var v2 = std::move(v1);
    printMemoryUsage();

    v2 = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
    printMemoryUsage();

}
```

Class Var:

```
class Var {
private:
    std::string varName;

public:
    explicit Var(std::string _varName) : varName(std::move(_varName)) {
        std::cout << "ctor\n" << &varName << std::endl;
    } //ctor

    Var(const Var &otherVar) = delete;

    Var(Var &&otherVar) noexcept : varName{std::move(otherVar.varName)} { 
       std::cout << "mtor" << std::endl; 
    }

    Var& operator=(const std::string& var) {
        std::cout << "copy\n";
        varName = var;
        return *this;
    }

    Var& operator=(std::string&& var) {
        std::cout << "move\n";

        varName = std::move(var);
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~Var() { std::cout << "dtor" << std::endl; };

    bool operator==(const Var &rhs) const {
        return varName == rhs.varName;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Var &rhs) const {
        return !(rhs == *this);
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Var &var) {
        os << "varName: " << var.varName;
        return os;
    }

};
```

I have a class "Var" with one field of std::string type.
I construct a Var v1 and then a Var v2 using the move constructor on v1, and that work great because the memory allocation remains the same.

Then I want to assign a new varName to v2 (v2 = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"). Since I have allocated a new constant string, the total memory allocation increases. But then there is an assignment to the varName field (in method Var& operator=(std::string&& var)) so I would expect that the previously allocated memory that holds "0011223344556677889" in varName were freed, and then varName were assigned to the newly allocated memory block.

So in other word, how can I free the memory allocated for the varName field and allocate a new memory block to be pointed by varName? Am I using the move semantic correctly?

Comment: "explicit Var(std::string _varName)" since _varName isn't a reference it will construct a copy. Then you move it's data which is slightly better than a second copy, but would have been more efficient to pass a reference of the original object and copy that. Your other functions look ok, but usually the arguments are an instance of the class, rather than a member of the class

Comment: What is your output and what did you expect to be different?

Answer (score 0):

`v2 = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"`. I think this might be the first cause for your misunderstanding. A string literal has type `const char[N]`, not `std::string`.

Anyway, there is no guarantee that `std::string::operator=` allocates a new memory block. When the existing allocation is large enough, it's simpler and faster to reuse that. So, your question : "how can I free the memory allocated for the varName field and allocate a new memory block to be pointed by varName?" has no simple answer.

In theory, you could call `.clear()` followed by `.shrink_to-fit()` but even that is non-binding. There's just no good reason in normal C++ programs to do what you want, so there is no method in `std::string` for that.

Comment: "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" will do an implicit conversion to std::string due to the operator=(const std::String&). At this point you've already allocated another heap buffer assuming it's longer than std::Strings small string optimization, and have lost the game.

Comment: @Justin: It's not entirely trivial - C++ has a rule against 2 user-defined conversions - but in this case the left of `=` is already a `Var` object so it doesn't count as two conversions. However, the temporary `std::string` is a temporary, and therefore the overload resolution should select `std::string&&` over `const std::string&`.

Comment: @MSaltrs Wouldn't it have to be true as there is no operator= or copy ctor that takes a const char*. So either it does this or doesn't compile? At some point that string literal needs to become a std::string to be used for any functions? And once you've constructed it once, even if you move you still have the ctor overhead.

Comment: @Justin: Even if there would be a `Var::operator=(const char*)`, you keep the issue that the characters from the string literal need to be copied once to heap-allocated memory. That's the unavoidable bit. What you want to avoid is a heap-to-heap copy, and using moves is a good way to prevent that.

Comment: How about using std::string literals? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: @Sebastian: You can use the same logic. Since you get non-const strings as a result, there must be a copy somewhere because the literal itself is immutable. But you can avoid additional copies.

Answer (score 0):

I've added debug output in the `new` and `delete` overloads: https://godbolt.org/z/Tn8EYfxPx

With that I get the following output:

```
Current memory usage (bytes): 0
allocate 20                        <--- Var v1{"0011223344556677889"};
ctor
0x7fff040c9d88
Current memory usage (bytes): 20
mtor                               <--- Var v2 = std::move(v1);
Current memory usage (bytes): 20
allocate 20                        <--- v2 = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
move
delete 20
Current memory usage (bytes): 20
dtor
delete 20
dtor
```

As you can see when you write `v2 = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";` the compiler invokes `Var& operator=(std::string&& var) {`. For this the C string is first converted to `std::string` causing the allocation. Then the `move` happens and swaps the 2 strings around. Last the temporary string is destructed causing the `delete` of the old contents of `v2`.

Note: the move could also `delete` the old contents directly but I think it swaps contents as that is faster in some cases.

PS: You could add a assignment operator using `string_view` that resizes the string and copies the contents. This would avoid the allocation and deallocation for the `std::string` temporary.

Comment: Thank you very much, that implicit conversion I didn't notice. 
But I can't understand why Clang does not do the same job of gcc. I also discovered that if I use Var& operator=(const char* var) instead of Var& operator=(std::string&& var), than Clang works fine (obvously now there is no implicit conversion). 
But this does not resolve the fact that with Clang I do not have deallocation of the temporary string. Any suggestion why?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/PPT5vEPE9 clang calls `void operator delete(void *) noexcept` instead of `void operator delete(void *, std::size_t)`. I guess the optimizer doesn't figure out the size of the allocated string and therefore doesn't call the delete with size.

Comment: Update: I am using gcc now and for some reason it doesn't call delete. I can't figure out why. I didn't change anything, the code is the same that you compile in Compiler Explorer. I smell some kind of optimization that I don't see

Comment: @MarcoPellizzoni Calls to new/delete may be merged. Potentially you could have just one big new and delete call. Compilers (gcc/clang) aren't smart enough to eliminate the strings completely and just print the original `const char *` last I checked. And your strings should be larger than the small string optimization.

Comment: yeah you're probably right. Thank you a lot, I learned something from this